# MySQL+PHP Adding Products to Product Table using DropDown List to select product Category from Category table

Tags: php, mysql

I have 5 Tables created in MySQL, 4 are different products'Clothes, Toys, Electronics and Books' with few columns (ID, productName and price)  and one table is Categories with (categoryID and categoryName). I'm trying to make page where after login in admin can add a product and assign it to category, and later be able to add more Categories. I have a Drop-down List of categories where user chose a category he wishes to add a product to and then using provided from fills in necessary information like the product name and price. Unfortunately I keep getting an error which I cannot overcome  Help ;( Here is my Code:

```
    //this creates the drop down list of categories...

//Database connection 
$server = '*********';
$username = '********';
$password = '******';

//The name of the schema created in MySQL Workbench
$schema = '******';

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password, 
                [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);

 $results = $pdo1->query('SELECT * FROM categories ');
echo 'Chose Category:';

echo "<form action='add_products.php' method='POST'>";
echo "<select name='catForm'>";

foreach ($results as $row) {
    echo "<label>Chose Category:</label><option value='" . $row['catName'] . "'>" . $row['catName'] . "</option>";
}
echo "</select>";
echo "<input type='submit' value='Add' name='submitSelectCat' />
    </form>";

    if (isset($_POST['submitSelectCat']))
    {

        $myvalue=$_POST['catForm'];
        echo $myvalue;
    }
```

//-----------------------------------

```
    //This is what happens when button was pressed


//Database connection 
$server = '*********';
$username = '**********';
$password = '**********';

//The name of the schema created in MySQL Workbench
$schema = '********';

$pdo = new PDO('mysql:dbname=' . $schema . ';host=' . $server, $username, $password, 
                [ PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION]);



$pdo->query('INSERT INTO ' . $myvalue  . '(productName, price) 
        VALUES(
            "' . $_POST['productName'] . '",
            "' . $_POST['price'] . '"
        )');
            echo $myvalue;




}
//The form was not submitted, display the form
else {
?>

<form action="add_products.php" method="POST">

        <label>Product Name:</label>
        <input type="text" name="productName" />

        <label>Price:</label>
        <input type="text" name="price" value="£" />        

        <input type="submit" value="Add" name="submitAddProduct" />


    </form>

<?php
}

?>
```

( ! ) Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(productName, price) VALUES( "thissssssssss", "£1111" )' at line 1 in /srv/http/public_html/add_products.php on line 78

( ! ) PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '(productName, price) VALUES( "thissssssssss", "£1111" )' at line 1 in /srv/http/public_html/add_products.php on line 78

```
    LINE 77-    "' . $_POST['price'] . '"
LINE - 78   )');
```

Notice: Undefined variable: myvalue in /srv/http/public_html/add_products.php on line 74

LINE 74 - $pdo->query('INSERT INTO ' . $myvalue  . '(productName, price)

Comment: which is line 55?

Comment: $test1 = $pdo->prepare('INSERT INTO' . $results . '(productName, price)

Comment: And where does that `$results` come from, above?  Shouldn't you be putting a table name in there?

Comment: $results. is whatever you pick from the drop down menu at least i hope it is

Comment: so if you select Category1 from the dropdown menu the second table where the error is should be using that choice as a name of the table you want to insert stuff

Comment: This is Updated code. I now chose a category from the drop down list and sore it in a $myvalue. i later print the value to make sure it worked. then in second form i enter stuff I want added in that table and insert it into a table that i chose from the dropdown.

Comment: Man, check the error message. You are trying to inset a pound symbol as a price. I bet the price field is expecting a float or double value.

Comment: I'm trying to work this out, are these 2 separate files? It seems that your errors are because ```$myvalue``` is undefined.

Comment: "Price" is a column in MySQL and it accepts VARCHAR. I can declare any variable on the top as a string that is a name of the table i want to insert to and use this variable when inserting and it works fine. Its just when i use the variable created from the dropdown it all goes to ...*

Comment: And no. All in one file. $myValue is defined because just before i try to use it in inserting to the table its echo onto a page and it seem to work fine.

Comment: No, $myvalue is NOT set unless you set it in add_products prior to creating your sql syntax

Comment: Well The page works as follows. There is a dropdown menu from which i chose any of the 4 categories. i press the button and assign the choice to $myvalue. I then echo $myvalue to make sure it worked. Then a second form is under to which i input some data and insert it into a table which was picked before from the dropdown menu and assigned value to $myvalue